# Can I avoid initializing objects every time on load?

Tags: vb.net, initialization, constants, startup

I keep looking for some tips here and can't find any - maybe I'm asking the question wrong, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I'm working on a program to visually view and plan our shop floor production. I want to capture our machines as their own Objects/Classes (based on type, constraints, yadda yadda). The catch is that I have 33 machines.

The constraints of my machines will not be changing often (pretty much never). All I've come up with so far is storing the values in either a txt file or table and reading them in when the form loads. To do this, however, it behooves me to check the directory of the file (and the file itself) for its existence, at which point creating a "write" sub would require hard-coding all the values anyways (so why not just run the same "write" sub on load in lieu of the "read" sub).

So my question(s) here is(/are): Is there an elegant way to store my machines and their constraints? Or do I have to initialize them each time? And if I have to initialize each time, does reading from a txt file make sense? Or is there some superior method?

Thanks.

P.s. Building in Visual Studio, using VB.NET, and have only about 6 months of actual programming under my belt, so I'm pretty green.

Comment: if you serialized a `List(Of myMachines)` you could handle the initalizing and reading from a file parts with 5 or 6 lines of code; otherwise pretty vague

Comment: 33 is a *very* small number.  Have you noticed any actual performance problem that you're trying to address here?  You could serialize the entire list to a file and de-serialize it back to a list every time the application starts and it would take milliseconds.  Persisting the information to a database and retrieving it back again would be just as straightforward.  It's not really clear what you're asking or why.

Comment: They all have distinct names, so the actual process of reading the file would be easy. My reluctance is that the procedure would have to run every time the program loads. This might just be how little I know about software development, but I would love to bypass having to load the same constants every single time, despite them never needing to be updated.

I ask because I hate redundancy. If there is a way that I don't need to read the same data repeatedly, I'd love to know it. But if no such thing exists, then I'm S.O.L..

Comment: Create your textfile and add it as a ressource. That way you can be sure it is there at any time and how you want it.

Comment: Really the only way to persist the data without having to load *at all* would be to create 33 individual forms, with each machine's values hard coded as constants. Which is a really terrible idea. Otherwise, and almost as terrible, is you could have a form and create 33 instance of it for each machine, create the forms once and instead of calling `New` every time, call `Show` and `Hide` to just toggle visibility. But really, you shouldn't do either of these things.

Comment: Look up `Xml Serialization`.

Comment: How many values per machine are we talking about?